# How to get nav-form on same line on mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar here that looks the way I want it on the desktop.

http://www.bootply.com/it7sRdkVIA

However, on the mobile, I don't want the search box on a different line. I want it so that it all displays on the same line. I want the search box to appear to the right of Calcs brand name.

How do I get both a navbar-Brand and navbar-form to both be on the same line in a mobile view?

Comment: give that form, these properties in mobile view, `float: left; margin-top: 6px;    margin-bottom: 0; padding: 0 1px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track you just need to position it with some CSS.

*I also adjusted your dropdown to use the class `navbar-right` See [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment).

See working example.

```css
.navbar-custom .formSearch {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 8px;
  left: -65px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-custom .formSearch {
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    left: -85px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand goto-home-page">Calcs</a>

      <form class="formSearch" role="search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a calculator" id="txtCalcSearcher">
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Username <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li> <a href="#" id="import">Import</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#" id="btnLogout">Sign out</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```